Tabbing inside of MUI Data-Grid dialog closes it
I have a MUI Data Grid where the user is allowed to cell edit values.
One of the cells render a MUI Dialog via renderEditCell. In that dialog there are several input fields (MUI TextField) which I want to be able to tab through.
My problem now is, that as soon as I tab to the next field, the dialog is closed because the next cell of the data grid is focused.
I've tried to ignore the tab key in onCellEditStop with event.defaultMuiPrevent = true. With that, the dialog no longer closes, but the focus doesn't switch to the next input field. As far as I understood, I think this is because the event is first handled in the parent and thus the default is also prevented within the dialog.
I have a minimal reproducible example here (relevant code in onCellEditStop is commented out).
How can I fix this? Is there a different approach?

You can attach onKeyDown event on Dialog component and check if pressed key code is Tab then prevent the event bubbling up to the parent.
onKeyDown={(e) => {
 if (e.code === "Tab") {
   e.stopPropagation();
 }
}}

Here's the complete code:
CustomField.tsx
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import DialogContent from "@mui/material/DialogContent";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { useGridApiContext } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import React from "react";

export default function CustomField({ id, field, row }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
  const apiRef = useGridApiContext();

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    apiRef.current.stopCellEditMode({ id, field });
  };

  return (
    <Dialog
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
      fullWidth
      maxWidth="md"
      onKeyDown={(e) => {
        if (e.code === "Tab") {
          e.stopPropagation();
        }
      }}
    >
      <DialogContent>
        <TextField
          fullWidth
          label="Min"
          name="min"
          size="small"
          sx={{ m: 1 }}
          type="number"
          defaultValue={row.validationDef?.min || ""}
        />

        <TextField
          fullWidth
          label="Max"
          name="max"
          size="small"
          sx={{ m: 1 }}
          type="number"
        />
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

App.tsx
import {
  DataGrid,
  GridColDef,
  GridRenderEditCellParams,
} from "@mui/x-data-grid";

import Alert from "@mui/material/Alert";
import CustomField from "./CustomField";

export default function App() {
  const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    {
      field: "attribute",
      headerName: "Attribute",
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      field: "customField",
      headerName: "Dialog Field",
      flex: 1.5,
      renderEditCell: (params: GridRenderEditCellParams) => (
        <CustomField {...params} />
      ),
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      field: "type",
      type: "singleSelect",
      headerName: "Type",
      editable: true,
      valueOptions: [
        "COMPLEX",
        "BOOLEAN",
        "STRING",
        "NUMBER",
        "DATE",
        "DATETIME",
      ],
    },
  ];

  const rows = [
    {
      id: 1,
      attribute: "a name",
      customField: "double click me",
      type: "COMPLEX",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <Alert severity="info">
        <ul>
          <li>Double click on the value in the "Dialog Field" column</li>
          <li>Click into the first input field</li>
          <li>Try to tab to the next input field</li>
        </ul>
      </Alert>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        rowHeight={40}
        hideFooter={true}
      />
    </div>
  );
}


I was hoping for a solution that would be applied to the DataGrid, but your solution works well too. Thank you!

This should do it, I thought about the same solution
